# If $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is unreliable, what will I use instead to ensure web-app integrity?

Tags: php

I thought I was being really slick by using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable to ***guarantee*** my script was being called from the appropriate page.

Luckily, when I performed a `header('Location: yourPathHere.php')` redirect in my testing browser, it wouldn't set the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable. So I looked it up at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php, only to find this...

> 'HTTP_REFERER'
>
> The address of the page (if any) which
> referred the user agent to the current
> page. This is set by the user agent.
> Not all user agents will set this, and
> some provide the ability to modify
> HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short,
> it cannot really be trusted.

So my question is: How can I ***guarantee*** my page is being navigated to from a trusted source?

EDIT: To clarify questions regarding the comments section. I'm trying to avoid XSRF (cross-site request forgery).

Comment: You can't.  What are you afraid of?

Comment: In short, XSS (cross-site scripting).

Comment: @Zak: How does XSS relate to "where are my visitors coming from"? Im confused, please elaborate.

Comment: @Zak you can't guarantee the integrity of the referrer variable.  There are solutions to potential XSS problems, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+prevent+xss Consider elaborating what exactly you want to protect against

Comment: There are better solutions to XSS than ensuring the reffering page is correct. The referring page can be faked.

Comment: What you are looking for is called "CSRF tokens", not XSS whatever.

Comment: You are correct, I meant to say XSRF (cross-site request forgery). My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: With lighttpd and nginx this is possible to some extent, but without help from the server you'd be out of luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relying on any user originated input for request verification is almost no better than no verification at all.

You should read this [section on CSRF countermeasures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Other_approaches_to_CSRF) from Wikipedia for a basic outline of available approaches to tackling the issue.

In short:

Web sites have various CSRF countermeasures available:

- Requiring a secret, user-specific token in all form submissions and side-effect URLs prevents CSRF; the attacker's site cannot put the right token in its submissions
- Requiring the client to provide authentication data in the same HTTP Request used to perform any operation with security implications (money transfer, etc)
- Limiting the lifetime of session cookies
- Ensuring that there is no crossdomain.xml file granting unintended access to Flash movies

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I just didn't know how to express it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is the referring page also under your control?
If so, you could try setting some server-side session variables when a user visits page A, and check for them when he tries to access page B.
But like other respondants have said - this is not related to preventing XSS ..

Comment: You are correct, I meant to say XSRF (cross-site request forgery). My apologies for the confusion.